# Is there a way to use expressions to update a document in the MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

For example:

```
_users.UpdateOne(x => x.Id == userId, y => y.Balance *= interestRate);
```

I know something like this is possible with the update builder, but it seems to take more code and is less readable. Would there be a way to do something similar but with some kind of custom method?

Comment: There is no reason you couldn't write your own expression system to do this, as you are aware of the types. You would just have to assign the setters to actually be `document.Update.Set(..)`

Comment: Where does that document object come from? Would I have to fetch the user object then cast it to a BsonDocument?